How to stop Steam from automatically running in background (Linux)
Basically exactly this question regarding Windows
but for Linux, Fedora 40. I imagine the answer has something to do with systemd, for which Steam has a couple files. Other than comments, they seem to only contain file descriptor limit overrides:

/usr/lib/systemd/system.conf.d/01-steam.conf and
/usr/lib/systemd/user.conf.d/01-steam.conf

I've been doing the occasional pkill steam and I'd like to upgrade that practice. pgrep shows steam, steam-runtime-l, and about 10 steamwebhelpers.

Since you've mentioned specific systemd configuration files for Steam, so here is how you can do so.
First open the terminal application and run the following command to confirm which systemd services are related to Steam:
systemctl --user list-units | grep steam

Look for any units that have "steam" in their name.
If you identify a service related to Steam, disable it so it doesn't start automatically:
systemctl --user disable steam.service

Replace steam.service with the actual service name you find.
To ensure Steam doesn't start automatically, you can create a systemd override configuration.
Create a directory for the service override if it doesn't already exist:
mkdir -p ~/.config/systemd/user/steam.service.d

Create an override file:
nano ~/.config/systemd/user/steam.service.d/override.conf

Add the following command to prevent Steam from starting:
[Service] ExecStart=

After making changes, reload the systemd user configuration to apply them:
systemctl --user daemon-reload

Stop any running Steam services:
systemctl --user stop steam.service

Also, manually kill any remaining Steam processes if necessary:
pkill steam

